# Mongoose Query Returning Undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got a Mongoose query that definitely should be working as far as I can tell, but is returning `undefined` and I can't figure out why.

Here's the query:

```
...
var perPage = config.perpage;
var page = req.query.page > 0 ? req.query.page : 0;

db.Mail.find().select('-body -scraped').limit(perPage).skip(perPage * page).sort('-createdAt').exec(function (err, mail) {
...
```

Here's the schema just in case:

```
var mongoose    = require("mongoose");
var timestamps  = require("mongoose-simpletimestamps").SimpleTimestamps;
var Schema      = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId    = Schema.ObjectId;

var oneday = 24 * 60 * 60;

var mailSchema = new Schema({
  subject: { type: String, required: true },
  body: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true },
  status: { type: String, required: true },
  processed: {
    area: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Area'},
    url: String
  },
  scraped: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed },
  properties: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Property' }],
  notifications: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Notification' }],
  datestamp: {
    type: Number,
    default: function () { return Math.floor(Date.now() / oneday ); }
  }
});
mailSchema.plugin(timestamps);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Mail", mailSchema);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: From a first quick look I would say that the order of the operations matters. If you limit before skipping you might end up with nothing. Moreover I would do the `sort` before skipping/limiting too.

Comment: What's returning `undefined`?

Comment: There's no way the limit could cause it to return undefined, but I'll check the order and see if that makes a difference. And mail is returning undefined.

Comment: If you do a find() it's afaik impossible to get undefined (if the result is empty you should get an empty array), unless there's an error. Have you logged `err`?